# Why is PHP's explode wrong?

Tags: php

Here is the PHP code:

```
var_dump($value);
```

```
string(103) "0e0cU\0Z‚dddd.is.moar.awesome‚A6A32C2074B787893DF506F6F466F5919516C44F3"
```

```
var_dump(explode(',', $value));
```

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(103) "0e0cU\0Z‚dddd.is.moar.awesome‚A6A32C2074B787893DF506F6F466F5919516C44F3"
}
```

Why isn't the string being split on the comma?

Comment: @Havelock huh? `explode(',', $value)` theres the comma specified right there, no?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do, why use str_split at all? why isn't explode(',', $value) enough?

Comment: Because it's not a comma. What have there is the character `U+201A`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the character in the string you're trying to `explode()` is not a comma – well, not [an ASCII comma: `,` (decimal code point `44`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2C/index.htm). The comma in the string is a [Unicode Character 'SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK' (decimal code point `8218`).](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201A/index.htm)

Try this in your JavaScript console:

```
> '‚' === ','
  false
```

Comment: Mind. Blown. How are two identical literals unequal?

Comment: @ChrisCooney they're not identical literals.

Comment: In all honesty, it looks like what of those sketchy mathematical proofs that wind up with something like `2=1`, but yeah. I know different encodings mean different things. Odd!

Comment: @ChrisCooney no, it has nothing to do with different encodings. It has nothing to do with encodings at all. They're characters that look very similar, but are not, just like `c` and `o` look similar but are completely different. One just happens to fall outside of ASCII.

Comment: Oh wow! Interesting how these little things crop up over time isn't it?

Comment: Now when you say, it's clear, but how do you come to check the code point?

Comment: @agim primarily through experience with this sort of thing. If you're asking _how_ I did it, I opened my browser's JavaScript console, and (by copy-and-pasting) entered `'‚'.charCodeAt(0)`.

Comment: @MattBall That was not what I wanted to ask, there are many ways to find out the code point - I would do it in python - but what I meant is, why did you suspect, the commas are two different characters? Hope you know what I mean :)

Comment: @agim for one, they don't look identical on my screen. Also, like I said, I've run into this sort of thing before, so I've learned to look for it when debugging "strange" string behaviors. For example, I recently helped a coworker debug why Java's `String#trim()` was not removing trailing white space from strings like this: `"foo "`. Turned out that it was no ordinary space (ASCII 32) but [a Unicode nonbreaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm), which `String#trim()` does not remove (facepalm). Like @Hiroto said, "it's always unicode."

Comment: Ill leave your answer as correct, but it is missing a key point that I mentioned in my answer. If you'd like to incorporate that into your answer, I'll erase mine.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigation, the real problem was that the input string was in the Windows-1252 encoding. Therefore trying to replace U+201A didnt work until I converted it to unicode first.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think there's any way to have known that from the string in the question.

Comment: No, you could have before the edit. The clue would have been that the place where the comma was, it was represented by one byte not the three that the unicode representation would have shown. No worries though, alls well that ends well.