# Why is json_decode returning weird characters?

Tags: php, unicode

Why does the following code:
    var_dump(json_decode('"\u201A"'));
    echo json_decode('"\u201A"');

Print out:

```
string(3) "â€š"
â€š
```

Instead of:

```
string(1) "‚"
‚
```

[Here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201a/index.htm) is the link to the unicode page.

Furthermore, this could not be a browser display issue: note how the PHP output says that there are three characters.

Furthermore:

```
var_dump(str_split(json_decode('"\u201A"')));
```

Outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "â"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "€"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "š"
}
```

In context:

```
$unicodeChar = '\u201A';
$value = str_replace(json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"'), ',', $value);
```

isn't replacing the unicode character with the real one. Why?

Comment: Anytime you see unexpected `â` chars in output, you've got a character set mismatch somewhere. UTF-8 text being output in some OTHER charset environment, e.g. iso-8859-1

Comment: Why don't you read the answers/comments in your previous question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993165/why-is-phps-explode-wrong You've been told what the problem is. \u201a is **NOT** a comma character.

Comment: @MarcB right, thats why i'm trying to replace the unicode character with the real one, am i missing something? (`$search = json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"')` NOT `','`). Furthermore, note that the php says that the string contains 3 characters, not 1. So it cannot be a browser issue.

Comment: That's not what PHP says. PHP says the string contains 3 bytes. And UTF-8 characters are of variable byte width. It's just that. See [What every programmer absolutely, positively needs to know about encodings and character sets to work with text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: @mario That would make sense, but in this case `str_split` is returning three characters, unlike the previous question where it returned one for each character (no matter how many bytes). Furthermore, the php doc for `str_split` says: "each chunk will be one character in length."

Comment: Well, the php manual is wrong. Each chunk will be one byte, not one character. And interpretation of output bytes is up to the browser, depending on charset.

Comment: @mario that doesnt make sense seeing as how its an explicit option: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php (furthermore, it split by character not byte in the last question)

Comment: Please actually read the link given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `','` directly in your source file, you are writing a string of bytes which depend on the encoding used in your text editor. From what I can see your text editor is using Windows-1252/"ANSI" I.E. you are writing the byte `0x82` in your file.

PHP strings are byte arrays with unmanaged encoding so anything goes.

`json_decode` returns results in UTF-8, so the low quotation mark is 3 bytes in PHP strings: `0xE2 0x80 0x9A`.

So you are trying to replace `0x82` and there is no match as you can see.

You can see this is true with this code:

```
<?php
$win1252 = ",";
$utf8 = json_decode('"\u201A"');
echo bin2hex($win1252) . "\n<br>";
echo bin2hex($utf8);
```

---

To avoid headaches you must work with a single encoding at all times. Otherwise, for correct handling, you will end up with obscure conversion code all over the place or embarrassing character encoding bugs. I suggest choosing UTF-8 because `json_*` doesn't work with anything else as an obvious reason.

The first things you need to do is to set your text editor to save files in UTF-8 and declare UTF-8 for the browser:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Next comes database transmission **and** storage encoding (separate things), and other possible places where text<->bytes interpretation happens in your application.

Comment: You have the order of arguments to str_replace wrong. The string is actually coming from phpseclib's parsing of an X509 cert. Oddly enough, the first few bytes `bin2hex($value)` outputs 306530630603551d11045c305a8214... which contains 82. So the last questions answer was wrong.

Comment: @chacham15 that doesn't look like text at all, it looks like binary data because 06 and 03 are not used in text. I don't have `str_replace` in my answer so how can I have the arguments wrong :P

Comment: "So you are trying to replace 0x82 and there is no match as you can see." I meant that I am not trying to replace anything in `json_decode('"\u201A"')`, I am trying to replace that byte sequence with the ',' byte sequence in $value.

Comment: @chacham15 sure but it doesn't change what I am saying in principle. Regardless of what should get replaced where, you can't possibly have expected results when the strings are in different character encodings.

Comment: Yes, you are quite correct. The real problem was that the input string wasnt utf8, but rather Windows-1252. Thanks.